# Apache2 web server url

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Hello I use Apache2 web server for my web site.
I have a question :
when I write this url [www.monsite.com](http://www.monsite.com) in the browser, I obtain the page it work! of apache (index.html).

Instead, when I write https://monsite.com on the browser, I obtain the right page, the welcome page of my web site.

I think is just refferal in the 000-monsite.conf, but I would like to be sure.

Thank you for your information.

Comment: Can you share your config ?

Comment: Hello Thank you for your help. I resolve the problem. I have to put an virtualhost 443 for https.